# Trying to check if urlreferrer is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following line of code to check if the `UrlReferrer` is `null`

`@if (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath == null)`

It just gives me an error of:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I'm new to asp and have hunted around but can't seem to find anything that will answer my question.  The thing that confuses me is if I replace null like so:

`@if (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath == "/Home")`

...and the AbsolutePath is indeed /Home, the code works fine, surely I'm asking for the same thing here but with `null`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Request.UrlReferrer** is null if there is no referrer, which makes your reference to **Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath** (a property on a null object) throw a null reference exception.

Instead, try;

```
@if (Request.UrlReferrer == null)
```

Comment: You might wanna consider testing both however. @if (Request.UrlReferrer == null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath)) (If the 1st is null, then the 2nd will not trigger and therefore avoid the exception. If the 1st has data but the referer path is null or empty, the condition will still fail as there isnt really a referer even if the object wasnt null)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have current path of your current page, you might use this one:

```
var absoluteUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string returnUrl = absoluteUrl.Replace(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "/");
```